# How to replace java6 with java8 in Mac OSX?

Tags: java, macos

I hava install java8

[image]

but `java -version` output:

```
java -version
java version "1.6.0_65"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.6.0_65-b14-466.1-11M4716)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 20.65-b04-466.1, mixed mode)
```

How to use latest version? 
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out [this how-to](http://www.mkyong.com/java/how-to-set-java_home-environment-variable-on-mac-os-x/) to change your java home path to the java 8 home

Answer (score 1):

Use this command to update JAVA_HOME variable:

```
export JAVA_HOME=`/usr/libexec/java_home -v 1.8`
```